# "plugin:vite:vue]""@vue/compiler-sfc"<script setup> cannot contain ES module exports

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, vite

Following the setup guide for Vuejs,the following vue inside src/views/main/index.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <navigation-vue></navigation-vue>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import navigationVue from './components/navigation/index.vue'
export default {
  name: 'index'
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

I get the following error from Vite:

> [plugin:vite:vue] [@vue/compiler-sfc]  cannot contain ES module exports. If you are using a previous version of , please consult the updated RFC at https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/227.

How to solve this problem
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[plugin:vite:vue] [@vue/compiler-sfc]  **cannot contain ES module exports**. If you are using a previous version of , please consult the updated RFC at https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/227.

so delete the following code

```
export default {
  name: 'index'
}
```

then the error disappeared